# android getNodeValue data with ascii

Tags: android, xml, parsing, ascii

i have such a problem.
i have to parse xml and get value with ascii encoded caracters.
a part of my xml

```
 <response>
    <object>
    <id>793675</id>
    <name>&#381;irm&#363;n&#371;</name>
...
```

to get a value `name` i use functions

```
public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }

public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
             Node child;
             if( elem != null){
                 if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                     for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                         if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  || child.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE || child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                             return child.getNodeValue();
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
             return "";
      }
```

such way :

```
Document doc = XMLfromString(xml);
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("object");
Element e = (Element)nodes.item(0);
String restName = Html.fromHtml(getValue(e, "name")).toString();
```

but in result i have only value, which contains of characters before `#` 
i have only `&` in `restName`
ie string is truncated to `#`
why?  the character `#` is allowed in the xml, isnt it?
How can i get a full string value?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Sax Parser and override method as shown below:

You might want to use sax default Handler. See if it works. If not might need to extend default Handler and override behavior of this method to store the value correctly. Where myURLString is a variable you define in you extended class. This variable can then be accessed in endElement method for eample. you have total control over this here.

So one way is to extend org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

```
     protected String myValueString;


    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
    {
       super.characters(ch, start, length);  // deal with escape values here.
        myValueString = ...

    }
```

then inside     endElement(){

```
     check if matches your type and if so use myValueString;
```